# jQuery in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I added an accordion for an attachment within index.html.erb 
where I have two tabs named 'users' and 'attachments'.

I also have resource routes defined for both users and attachments.

> navbar links

```
<li><%= link_to "Users", users_path %></li>
<li><%= link_to "Attachments", attachments_path %></li>
```

When I refresh the page from within the attachments tab and refresh the page I can see the accordion, but when I open the attachment tab with a link_to, I can't see the accordion.

How can I always see the accordion when I am in /attachments route

### Edit

> attachment.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".accordion").accordion( { collapsible: true } );
});
```

> index.html.erb (just necessary part)

```
<div class="accordion">
    <% Here some condition with each do |a| %>
        <h3><%= a %></h3> 
        <div>
            <% Here some condition with each do |b|  %>             
                <p><%= b %></p> 
            <% end %>
        </div> 
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: is it possible that you share more of the layout and javascript involved? Without it it would be very hard for you to get help here...

Comment: of course I can but like I said the problem is that accordion only works when I refresh the page from within the attachments tab. I didn't add the code because I think it works even if it only works for like I said

Comment: Try `$(document).on('ready page:load', function() {...});`

Comment: Thank you Vucko, the problem has been solved

Comment: Vucko, please write this as an answer so that i can choose as best answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 4: how to use $(document).ready() with turbo-links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links)